# loop through path list held in txt

Tags: python

I have the below bit of code that works a treat, it takes the path set in 'myfolder' and zips up all the file types associated with a shp (I didn't write it, some other clever spark did). However I want to be clever and loop through a text file that contains a list of lots of paths. I've got to grips with the concept of looping through a txt file and printing out the list of file paths, but i'm not sure how I would go about linking the two. Any help would be great.

Si

Simple Loop

```
items = 'shp_folders.txt'

with open (items) as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
        f.seek(0)
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```

Code to create zip files.

```
import zipfile, sys, os, glob, shutil  

# Set the folder that contains the ShapeFiles  
myFolder = "C:/data/shp/recycling/"  

def zipShapefile(myFolder):  

    # Check if folder exists  
    if not (os.path.exists(myFolder)):  
        print myFolder + ' Does Not Exist!'  
        return False  

    # Get a list of shapefiles  
    ListOfShapeFiles = glob.glob(myFolder + '*.shp')  

    # Main shapefile loop  
    for sf in ListOfShapeFiles:  
        print 'Zipping ' + sf  

        # Create an output zip file name from shapefile  
        newZipFN = sf[:-3] + 'zip'  

        # Check if output zipfile exists, delete it  
        if (os.path.exists(newZipFN)):  
            print 'Deleting '+newZipFN  
            os.remove(newZipFN)  
            if (os.path.exists(newZipFN)):  
                print 'Unable to Delete' + newZipFN  
                return False  

        # Create zip file object  
        zipobj = zipfile.ZipFile(newZipFN,'w')  

        # Cycle through all associated files for shapefile adding them to zip file  
        for infile in glob.glob( sf.lower().replace(".shp",".*")):  
            print 'zipping ' + infile + ' into ' + newZipFN  
            if infile.lower() != newZipFN.lower() :  
                # Avoid zipping the zip file!  
                zipobj.write(infile,os.path.basename(infile),zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)  

        # Close zipfile  
        print 'ShapeFile zipped!'  
        zipobj.close()  

    # Got here so everything is OK  
    return True  

# Call function to zip files  
b = zipShapefile(myFolder)  

if b:  
    print "Zipping done!"  
else:  
    print "An error occurred during zipping."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. I see that Tubeliar has responded to your comment, but I'll leave this answer here as it has a little more detail.

To fix the `NameError: name 'zipShapefile' is not defined` you need to import zipShapefile into the script that loops through `'shp_folders.txt'`.

So if the `def zipShapefile(myFolder):` stuff is in a file named `zipshapes.py`, in the same folder as the looping script, you'd put `from zipshapes import zipShapefile` up near the top of the looping script.

You also need to fix up `zipshapes.py` slightly so the stuff underneath the function definition doesn't get executed when you do the import. Like this:

**zipshapes.py**

```
import zipfile, sys, os, glob, shutil

def zipShapefile(myFolder):  
    # Check if folder exists  
    if not (os.path.exists(myFolder)):  
        print myFolder + ' Does Not Exist!'  
        return False  

    # Get a list of shapefiles  
    ListOfShapeFiles = glob.glob(myFolder + '*.shp')  

    # Main shapefile loop  
    for sf in ListOfShapeFiles:  
        print 'Zipping ' + sf  

        # Create an output zip file name from shapefile  
        newZipFN = sf[:-3] + 'zip'  

        # Check if output zipfile exists, delete it  
        if (os.path.exists(newZipFN)):  
            print 'Deleting '+newZipFN  
            os.remove(newZipFN)  
            if (os.path.exists(newZipFN)):  
                print 'Unable to Delete' + newZipFN  
                return False  

        # Create zip file object  
        zipobj = zipfile.ZipFile(newZipFN,'w')  

        # Cycle through all associated files for shapefile adding them to zip file  
        for infile in glob.glob( sf.lower().replace(".shp",".*")):  
            print 'zipping ' + infile + ' into ' + newZipFN  
            if infile.lower() != newZipFN.lower() :  
                # Avoid zipping the zip file!  
                zipobj.write(infile,os.path.basename(infile),zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)  

        # Close zipfile  
        print 'ShapeFile zipped!'  
        zipobj.close()  

    # Got here so everything is OK  
    return True  


def main():
    # Set the folder that contains the ShapeFiles  
    myFolder = "C:/data/shp/recycling/" 

    # Call function to zip files  
    b = zipShapefile(myFolder)  

    if b:
        print "Zipping done!"  
    else:
        print "An error occurred during zipping."  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With this modified version you can now safely import it into other scripts, and you can still run it like you used to.

**edit**

Does 'shp_folders.txt' have one path per line, with no extra stuff on each line? If so, Tubeliar's script needs a minor change to work properly.

```
from zipshapes import zipShapefile

def main():
    items = 'shp_folders.txt'

    with open(items, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            zipShapefile(line.rstrip())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `line.rstrip()` gets rid of all white space that's on the line after the path, so that the string that `zipShapefile()` gets is a proper path with no added garbage on the end. Even if there are no spaces hiding on the ends of the lines there will be an End Of Line (EOL) marker, i.e. a `\n`, a `\r`, or a `\r\n`, depending on your OS.

---

The `main()` function in your answer zips the shape files in all the paths it finds in `shp_folders.txt` but then it goes on to try and zip folders in paths of the form `shp_folders.txt*.shp`. Of course, it won't find any, but it's still a bit silly. :) If the `zipShapefile()` function were a bit smarter it'd check that the path you pass it is actually a directory, but at the moment it merely checks whether the path exists, but it doesn't care if it's a directory or a plain file.

Anyway, here's a slightly improved version of your `main()` which now reports on each path that it processes.

```
def main():
    items = 'shp_folders.txt'

    with open(items, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            pathname = line.rstrip()
            print "Zipping %r" % pathname

            # Call function to zip files in pathname
            b = zipShapefile(pathname)
            if b:
                print "Zipping done!"
            else:
                print "An error occurred during zipping."
```

Comment: Thanks PM 2ring for your answer but i'm still a little confused by it.  Perhaps I've not explained myself very well. My shp_folder.txt contains lists of path names and the zipshapes.py contains the function to zip the contents of a folder, as defined as myFolder. What i'm looking to do is get the zipshapes.py to loop through each of the paths in the txt file and zip the contents of the that folder.

Comment: Cheers for this, I see how your looping now. full answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
items = 'shp_folders.txt'

with open (items) as f:
        for line in f:
            zipShapefile(line)
```

Also import the file that contains the zipShapefile function definition. Put the import statement on top and leave out the .py extension.

Comment: Cheers for this and I see what your doing but getting an error: NameError: name 'zipShapefile' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tubelair and PM 2ring for their help in coming up with the following answer.

```
import zipfile, sys, os, glob, shutil

def zipShapefile(myFolder):  
    # Check if folder exists  
    if not (os.path.exists(myFolder)):  
        print myFolder + ' Does Not Exist!'  
        return False  

    # Get a list of shapefiles  
    ListOfShapeFiles = glob.glob(myFolder + '*.shp')  

    # Main shapefilloop  
    for sf in ListOfShapeFiles:  
        print 'Zipping ' + sf  

        # Create an output zip file name from shapefile  
        newZipFN = sf[:-3] + 'zip'  

        # Check if output zipfile exists, delete it  
        if (os.path.exists(newZipFN)):  
            print 'Deleting '+newZipFN  
            os.remove(newZipFN)  
            if (os.path.exists(newZipFN)):  
                print 'Unable to Delete' + newZipFN  
                return False  

        # Create zip file object  
        zipobj = zipfile.ZipFile(newZipFN,'w')  

        # Cycle through all associated files for shapefile adding them to zip file  
        for infile in glob.glob( sf.lower().replace(".shp",".*")):  
            print 'zipping ' + infile + ' into ' + newZipFN  
            if infile.lower() != newZipFN.lower() :  
                # Avoid zipping the zip file!  
                zipobj.write(infile,os.path.basename(infile),zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)  

        # Close zipfile  
        print 'ShapeFile zipped!'  
        zipobj.close()  

    # Got here so everything is OK  
    return True  


def main():

    items = 'shp_folders.txt'
    myFolder = items

    with open(items, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            zipShapefile(line.rstrip())


    # Call function to zip files  
    b = zipShapefile(myFolder)  

    if b:
        print "Zipping done!"  
    else:
        print "An error occurred during zipping."  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Sure, you can paste the `zipShapefile()` definition into your looping script like that, if you like. But doing it with an import is better, since if you want to change the details of `zipShapefile()` you only need to change it in one place, rather than in every script you paste it into. But there's a little problem with your `main()`; I'll put an improved version into my answer.